# How to execute an .EXE file in Python with a given filepath?

Tags: python, executable, filepath, execute

I'm trying to write a bit of code to allow me to open up an exe file within Python, but I don't know the general way to make it properly. I would think that the code would look something like this:

```
exec(open("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\file-folder\\file.exe").read())
```

but when I compile the code using Geany, it gives me an error saying
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: character maps to undefined

I get the same error message when I try to write the file path with just one \ between each folder, but it gives me the same error in the compiler. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need to import os in your code if you wanna execute external files

```
import os
os.startfile(""C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\file-folder\\file.exe"")
```

Comment: This does the trick too, however, if the program produces any output then usually `os.startfile` is not recommended, unlike `subprocess.call` where it only continues when the output has been produced

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["fullPath\\yourExe.exe"])
```